# Is there a way to create a Dropdown-Menu/button in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, drop-down-menu, swiftui

I want to create a dropdown-menu in Xcode 11 Beta 1. But i have not found a way to to it in iOS.

I have tried it with the .hidden function and found the PullDownButton, but don‘t know how to set it up

I have created this Code

```
struct SwiftUIView : View {
@State var array = true
@State var buttonTitle = "Zeige Deteils"

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.array.toggle()

            }) {
                Text(buttonTitle)
            }


            if array {
                VStack(spacing: 1.0) {

                    Button(action: {
                        self.buttonTitle = "Schmelzpunkt"
                        self.array.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Schmelzpunkt")
                            .color(.white)
                            .padding(.all)
                    }
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    Button(action: {
                        self.buttonTitle = "Instrumentelle Analytik"
                        self.array.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Instrumentelle Analytik")
                            .color(.white)
                            .padding(.all)
                            }.background(Color.blue)
                            Button(action: {
                                self.buttonTitle = "Aussehen"
                                self.array.toggle()
                            }) {
                                Text("Aussehen")
                                    .color(.white)
                                    .padding(.all)
                                    }.background(Color.blue)

                                }
                                .padding(.top)
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

But can't find a was to animate the "poping-up" auf the hidden Buttons and want to the primary button to stay at its position

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Are you talking about `iOS` or `macOS`?

Answer (score 35):

In SwiftUI 2.0 (iOS 14+) you can make a dropdown menu with `Menu`.

```swift
Menu {
    Button {
        // do something
    } label: {
        Text("Linear")
        Image(systemName: "arrow.down.right.circle")
    }
    Button {
        // do something
    } label: {
        Text("Radial")
        Image(systemName: "arrow.up.and.down.circle")
    }
} label: {
     Text("Style")
     Image(systemName: "tag.circle")
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to increase width of items/tiles inside the menu? I can't seem to increase its width.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. (Probably to keep consistency throughout the OS and maybe also to prevent devs from abusing them, or they just didn't think to add that feature).

Comment: what's the style = 0 \1 ?  (it doesn't compile)

Answer (score 19):

Using `SwiftUI 2.0` you can also implement dropdown menu with `DisclosureGroup` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup) is ref.

```
GroupBox {
    DisclosureGroup("Menu 1") {
        Text("Item 1")
        Text("Item 2")
        Text("Item 3")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You might want to take a look at the `Picker`.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var selection = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $selection, label: Text("Zeige Deteils")) {
                Text("Schmelzpunkt").tag(1)
                Text("Instrumentelle Analytik").tag(2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Many good answers but what worked for me was something custom but very similar to **Menu** in **swiftui**

So start by creating your item for dropdown view.

example.

```
import SwiftUI


struct SampleDropDown: View {
    
  
    let action : (String?) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4){
            
            ForEach(0...3, id: \.self){ valueStore in
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    
                    
                }) {
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8) {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "bell")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                        
                        VStack (alignment: .leading){
                            Text("ANDROID" )
                                .font(.custom(Constants.FONT_REGULAR, size: 14))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.fromHex(Colors.TEXT_COLOR_PRIMARY))
                                .padding([.leading, .top], 4)
                            
                            Text("#jetpack")
                                .font(.custom(Constants.FONT_REGULAR, size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.fromHex(Colors.LIGHT_GREY))
                                .padding([.leading, .bottom], 2)
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }.foregroundColor(Color.fromHex(Colors.LIGHT_GREY))
                    
                }.frame(width: .none, height: .none, alignment: .center)
                
                
                Divider().background(Color.fromHex(Colors.DIVIDOR))
                
            }
            
        }.padding(.all, 12)
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).foregroundColor(.white).shadow(radius: 2))
        
    }
}

struct SampleDropDown_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        SampleDropDown(action: {data in}).padding()
    }
}
```

ui so far:

[image]

Now just add this as **Overlay** where you want to show or on top of which you want to show.

something like this.

example.

```
 @State var showStoreDropDown: Bool = false
  //ui 
 HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
                    
                    //here you UI goes 
                    
                }.overlay (
                    
                    VStack {
                        
                        if showTimeframeDropDown {
                            
                            Spacer(minLength: 40)
                            
                            SampleDropDown(action: { data in
                                
                            })
                            
                        }
                        
                    }, alignment: .topLeading
                    
                ).onTapGesture {
                    
                    showTimeframeDropDown.toggle()
                    
                }
```

result :

[image]

**Note**: This is just a sample code from my project, please change accordingly but the basic idea is to have drop-down view as an **overlay** on the host view.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use an overlay to display your dropdown. Otherwise, parents' layout will be wrong when you show and hide the dropdown.

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLDeS.png)

Here is a simple answer, and the complete answer could be found [here](https://medium.com/@zhuoshengjiang_26468/how-to-implement-a-dropdown-button-in-swiftui-239cf1bd8e8c)

```
struct Dropdown: View {
    var options: [DropdownOption]
    var onSelect: ((_ key: String) -> Void)?

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(self.options, id: \.self) { option in
                DropdownOptionElement(val: option.val, key: option.key, onSelect: self.onSelect)
            }
        }

        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(dropdownCornerRadius)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: dropdownCornerRadius)
                .stroke(Color.coreUIPrimary, lineWidth: 1)
        )
    }
}

struct DropdownButton: View {
    @State var shouldShowDropdown = false
    @Binding var displayText: String
    var options: [DropdownOption]
    var onSelect: ((_ key: String) -> Void)?

    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 30
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.shouldShowDropdown.toggle()
        }) {
            HStack {
                Text(displayText)
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 20)
                Image(systemName: self.shouldShowDropdown ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down")
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .cornerRadius(dropdownCornerRadius)
        .frame(height: self.buttonHeight)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: dropdownCornerRadius)
                .stroke(Color.coreUIPrimary, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .overlay(
            VStack {
                if self.shouldShowDropdown {
                    Spacer(minLength: buttonHeight + 10)
                    Dropdown(options: self.options, onSelect: self.onSelect)
                }
            }, alignment: .topLeading
        )
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: dropdownCornerRadius).fill(Color.white)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: How to set default Value ?

Answer (score 6):

```
           Text("Options")
            .contextMenu {
                Button(action: {
                    // change country setting
                }) {
                    Text("Choose Country")
                }

                Button(action: {
                    // enable geolocation
                }) {
                    Text("Detect Location")
                }
            }
```

taken from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-a-context-menu
Right click it to show the view

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers are good But everything needs to write from scratch. So I used a [UIKit DropDown](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) and create a UIViewRepresentable from it.

```
import SwiftUI
import DropDown

struct DropDownViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {

  @Binding var selectedItem: String //Send Selected item
  @Binding var isActive: Bool //Hide and Show the Dropdown

  let dropDown = DropDown()

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    return view
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    
    // The view to which the drop down will appear on
    dropDown.anchorView = uiView // UIView or UIBarButtonItem
    
    // The list of items to display. Can be changed dynamically
    dropDown.dataSource = ["Car", "Motorcycle", "Truck"]
    dropDown.dismissMode = .manual
    
    dropDown.selectionAction = { (index: Int, item: String) in
      print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
        selectedItem = item
        isActive = false
    }
    
    dropDown.direction = .bottom
    
    // Top of drop down will be below the anchorView
    dropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y:(dropDown.anchorView?.plainView.bounds.height)!)
    
    dropDown.cancelAction = {
        print("Drop down dismissed")
    }

    dropDown.willShowAction = {
        print("Drop down will show")
    }
    
    if isActive{
        dropDown.show()
    }else{
        dropDown.hide()
    }
   }
 }
```

**Note:** I just created it to access the basic features.

Comment: can you provide a sample how to use it

Comment: DropDownViewRepresentable(selectedItem: $selectedItem, isActive: $isActive)

Answer (score 1):

**Dropdown**

```
import SwiftUI

struct DropdownView<Control, Dropdown>: View where Control: View, Dropdown: View {
    @State var show: Bool = true
    let control: () -> Control
    let dropdown: () -> Dropdown

    var body: some View {
        control() // <--(1)
            .opacity(show ? 0.7 : 1.0)
            .zIndex(1)
            .onTapGesture {
                show.toggle()
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                Group {
                    if show {
                        dropdown() // <--(2)
                            .transition(.opacity)
                    }
                }
                .alignmentGuide(.bottom) { $0[.top] }
            }
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.2), value: show)
    }
}
```

// **Preview Example:**

```
struct DropdownView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            DropdownView { // <--(Use)
                Text("Dropdown")
                    .background(Color.red)
            } dropdown: {
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Button("Menu item 1111") {}
                        Button("Menu item 2222") {}
                        Button("Menu item 3333") {}
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                //.frame(width: 140)
                .background(Color.gray)
            }
            
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor") // example
        }
    }
}
```

Control limits the width of the dropdown menu:

[image]